# Python 3 minesweeper tkinter game

Tags: python, tkinter, minesweeper

I have just finished my minesweeper game using tkinter and would like to know how I could improve my program.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import randint

class setupwindow():
    def __init__(window): #window is the master object of the setup window
        window.root = Tk()
        window.root.title("Setup")
        window.root.grid()

        window.finish = "N"

        labels = ["Height:", "Width:", "Mines:"]
        window.label = ["","",""]
        window.entry = ["","",""]

        for i in range(3):
            window.label[i] = Label(text = labels[i])
            window.label[i].grid(row = i, column = 1)
            window.entry[i] = Entry()
            window.entry[i].grid(row = i, column = 2)

        window.startbutton = Button(text = "Start", command = lambda: setupwindow.onclick(window))
        window.startbutton.grid(column = 2)
        window.root.mainloop()

    def onclick(window):
        setupwindow.verification(window)
        if window.verf == "Y":
            window.finish = "Y"
            window.root.destroy()
            return window

    def verification(window):
        height = window.entry[0].get()
        width = window.entry[1].get()
        mines = window.entry[2].get()

        window.verf = "N"
        if height.isdigit() and width.isdigit() and mines.isdigit():
            height = int(height)
            width = int(width)
            mines = int(mines)

            if height > 0 and height <= 24:
                totalsquares = height * width

                if width > 0 and width <= 48:

                    if mines > 0:
                        if mines < totalsquares:
                            window.verf = "Y"
                            window.height = height
                            window.width = width
                            window.mines = mines

                        else:
                            messagebox.showerror("Invalid", "You cannot have more mines than squares!")
                    else:
                        messagebox.showerror("Invalid", "You can't play minesweeper without mines!")
                else:
                    messagebox.showerror("Invalid", "Width must be between 1 and 48 inclusive")
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Invalid", "Height must be between 1 and 24 inclusive")
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Invalid", "All values must be integers")


class gamewindow():
    def __init__(s, setup):  #s is the master object of the main game
        s.height = setup.height
        s.width = setup.width
        s.mines = setup.mines

        s.root = Tk()
        s.root.title("Minesweeper")
        s.root.grid()

        s.finish = "N"
        s.maingrid = list()
        for i in range(s.height):
            s.maingrid.append([])
            for x in range(s.width):
                s.maingrid[i].append(" ")
                s.maingrid[i][x] = Button(height = 0, width = 3, font = "Calibri 15 bold", text = "", bg = "gray90", command = lambda i=i, x=x: gamewindow.onclick(s, i, x))

                s.maingrid[i][x].bind("<Button-3>", lambda event="<Button-3>", i=i, x=x: gamewindow.rightclick(event, s, i, x))
                s.maingrid[i][x].grid(row = i, column = x)
                s.maingrid[i][x].mine = "False"

        totalsquares = s.height * s.width
        s.scoreneeded = totalsquares - s.mines
        s.score = 0

        indexlist = list()
        for i in range(totalsquares):
            indexlist.append(i)

        spaceschosen = list() #where the mines are going to be
        for i in range(s.mines):
            chosenspace = randint(0, len(indexlist) - 1)
            spaceschosen.append(indexlist[chosenspace])
            del indexlist[chosenspace]

        for i in range(len(spaceschosen)):
            xvalue = int(spaceschosen[i] % s.width)
            ivalue = int(spaceschosen[i] / s.width)

            s.maingrid[ivalue][xvalue].mine = "True"

        s.root.mainloop()


    def onclick(s, i, x):
        colourlist = ["PlaceHolder", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Purple", "Black", "Maroon", "Gray", "Turquoise"]

        if s.maingrid[i][x]["text"] != "F" and s.maingrid[i][x]["relief"] != "sunken":
            if s.maingrid[i][x].mine == "False":
                s.score += 1

                combinationsi = [1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1]
                combinationsx = [0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1] #All the surrounding spaces

                minecount = 0
                for combinations in range(len(combinationsi)):
                    tempi = i + combinationsi[combinations]
                    tempx = x + combinationsx[combinations]

                    if tempi < s.height and tempx < s.width and tempi >= 0 and tempx >= 0:
                        if s.maingrid[tempi][tempx].mine == "True":
                            minecount = minecount + 1

                if minecount == 0:
                    minecount = ""

                s.maingrid[i][x].configure(text = minecount, relief = "sunken", bg = "gray85")

                if str(minecount).isdigit():
                    s.maingrid[i][x].configure(fg = colourlist[minecount])

                if minecount == "":
                    for z in range(len(combinationsi)):
                        if s.finish == "N":
                            ivalue = i + int(combinationsi[z])
                            xvalue = x + int(combinationsx[z])

                            if ivalue >= 0 and ivalue < s.height and xvalue >=0 and xvalue < s.width:
                                if s.maingrid[ivalue][xvalue]["relief"] != "sunken":
                                    gamewindow.onclick(s, ivalue, xvalue)

                if s.score == s.scoreneeded and s.finish == "N":
                    messagebox.showinfo("Congratulations", "A winner is you!")
                    s.finish = "Y"
                    s.root.destroy()


            else:
                s.maingrid[i][x].configure(bg = "Red", text = "*")
                for a in range(len(s.maingrid)):
                    for b in range(len(s.maingrid[a])):
                        if s.maingrid[a][b].mine == "True":
                            if s.maingrid[a][b]["text"] == "F":
                                s.maingrid[a][b].configure(bg = "Green")
                            elif s.maingrid[a][b]["bg"] != "Red":
                                s.maingrid[a][b].configure(bg = "Pink", text = "*")

                        elif s.maingrid[a][b]["text"] == "F":
                            s.maingrid[a][b].configure(bg = "Yellow")

                messagebox.showinfo("GAME OVER", "You have lost")
                s.root.destroy()

    def rightclick(event, s, i, x):
        if s.maingrid[i][x]["relief"] != "sunken":
            if s.maingrid[i][x]["text"] == "":
                s.maingrid[i][x].config(text = "F")
            elif s.maingrid[i][x]["text"] == "F":
                s.maingrid[i][x].config(text = "?")
            else:
                s.maingrid[i][x].config(text = "")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup = setupwindow()
    if setup.finish == "Y":
        game = gamewindow(setup)
    quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

- Class names should normally use the CapWords convention. [#class-names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)
- Don't use spaces around the = sign when used to indicate a keyword argument, or when used to indicate a default value for an unannotated function parameter. [#whitespaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations)
- Always use self for the first argument to instance methods. [#function-and-method-arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments)
- There are other PEP-8 violations. Read complete document

2. [Guard clause](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html)

[What are guard clauses and how to use them?](https://medium.com/softframe/what-are-guard-clauses-and-how-to-use-them-350c8f1b6fd2)

3. Do not use `for i in range(len(list))` unless you really need index. Even if you do need it, use `enumerate` instead.

- [Loop Like A Native](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901081/only-index-needed-enumerate-or-xrange

4. Convert `range` to `list`

```
        indexlist = list()
        for i in range(totalsquares):
            indexlist.append(i)
```

is equivalent to
`indexlist = list(range(totalsquares))`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback however I'm unsure which part of the program you are referring to when you mentioned white spaces.

Comment: It's about functions/constructor calls like `.grid(row=i, column=x)`, `.config(text="F")` and `Button(height=0, width=3, ...)`